# Foreign keys update automation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, duplication

I'm on SQL Server 2014 and I need to clean a table from duplicates. Problem is: if a duplicate has references in other tables, that references should be updated to reference the chosen non-duplicate entity.

E.g., say a have a `Person` table:

```
+------+-------+-------+------------------------+
|  id  | fname | lname | mail                   | 
+------+-------+-------+------------------------+
| 1111 | John  | Smith | john.smith@example.com |
| 2222 | J.    | Smith | john.smith@example.com |
| 3333 | john  | smith | john.smith@example.com |
| 4444 | Smith | John  | john.smith@example.com |
+------+-------+-------+------------------------+
```

I need to delete `2222`, `3333`, `4444` and replace references around the database to these with a reference to `1111`. After this operation, a unique index on `mail` will be created.

My approach would be gathering all the distinct `mail` and building a  `id => [ ids ]` map (e.g. `1111 => [ 2222, 3333, 4444]`) and with a scripting language like Perl or PHP update all the tables which may have references to the duplicates and setting the correct `id`.

Since there are thousands of users and hundreds of tables with relations to them, I wonder if operations like this could be done directly in SQL Server function, with something like:

```
DELETE FROM [Person] WHERE [id] IN (2222, 3333, 4444) UPDATE REFERENCES WITH 1111
```

Comment: Hi Giovanni - presumably you know [what to do when someone answers your question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it
I changed this answer as I may have read the question incorrectly
Look at edit history if you are looking for something different

as for the fk

```
with CTE as 
(  select id, mail 
        , row_number() over (partition by mail order by id) as rn
   from table 
) 
update fk1  
   set fk1.fkID = cte1.ID 
  from fk as fk1 
  join cte as CTE2 
    on CTE2.ID = fk1.fkID
   and CTE2.rn > 1 
  join cte as CTE1 
    on CTE1.mail = CTE2.mail 
   and CTE1.rn = 1;
```

run above for addition fk

```
delete *  
from  
(  select id, mail 
        , row_number() over (partition by mail order by id) as rn
   from table 
) as t2 
where rn > 1;
```

Comment: Will this work given `id` being the primary key? I tried and I get "Cannot update identity column 'id'".

Comment: It makes not sense (to me) that a fkID would be an identity column.  Post the 'fk' table with definition and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` functionality to determine which duplicate key to keep, and which duplicate keys need to be updated to the one you're keeping.

As a test-bed, I setup the following

```
IF COALESCE(OBJECT_ID('dbo.T2'), 0) <> 0
DROP TABLE dbo.T2;

IF COALESCE(OBJECT_ID('dbo.T1'), 0) <> 0
DROP TABLE dbo.T1;

CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(
    T1_ID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_T1
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , SomeData VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.T2
(
    T2_ID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_T2
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , T1_ID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_T2_T1
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES dbo.T1(T1_ID)
    , SomeMoreData VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Here, I'm inserting duplicate values into "SomeData", with unique values for "T1_ID":

```
INSERT INTO dbo.T1(T1_ID, SomeData)
SELECT o.object_id,
    o.name
FROM sys.objects o
ORDER BY o.object_id;

INSERT INTO dbo.T1(T1_ID, SomeData)
SELECT o.object_id * -1,
    o.name
FROM sys.objects o
ORDER BY o.object_id;
```

And here we're generating the same duplicate rows for T2:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.T2(T1_ID, SomeMoreData)
SELECT o.object_id
    , o.name + '-' + o.type_desc
FROM sys.objects o
ORDER BY o.object_id;

INSERT INTO dbo.T2(T1_ID, SomeMoreData)
SELECT o.object_id * -1
    , o.name + '-' + o.type_desc
FROM sys.objects o
ORDER BY o.object_id;
```

To provide a mechanism for temporarily storing the mapping of old keys to new keys, I created the following table.  This allows multiple child tables to be easily updated, without needing to continuously recalculate the duplicates from the parent table:

```
IF COALESCE(OBJECT_ID('dbo.DupKeys'), 0) <> 0 
DROP TABLE dbo.DupKeys;

CREATE TABLE dbo.DupKeys 
(   OldKey INT NOT NULL
    , NewKey INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT CK_DupKeys
        CHECK (OldKey <> NewKey)
);
```

This populates the `DupKeys` tables.  Essentially, the idea here is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` partitioned by the column(s) that contain duplicate values (in your case this would be `fname, lname, mail`):

```
;WITH MinKeys
AS
(
    SELECT MinKey = T1.T1_ID
        , T1.SomeData
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.SomeData ORDER BY T1.T1_ID)
    FROM dbo.T1
)
INSERT INTO dbo.DupKeys (OldKey, NewKey)
SELECT OldKey = T1.T1_ID
    , NewKey = MinKeys.MinKey
FROM MinKeys
    INNER JOIN dbo.T1 ON MinKeys.SomeData = T1.SomeData
WHERE MinKeys.rn = 1
    AND MinKeys.MinKey <> T1.T1_ID;
```

This T-SQL will update the duplicate keys based on the mappings in the DupKeys table above:

```
UPDATE dbo.T2
SET T2.T1_ID = DupKeys.NewKey
FROM dbo.T2
    INNER JOIN dbo.DupKeys ON t2.T1_ID = DupKeys.OldKey
WHERE T2.T1_ID = DupKeys.OldKey;
```

The above could be used for multiple tables.

This can be used to eventually delete the duplicates from the parent table after all child tables have been updated.

```
DELETE
FROM dbo.T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.T2
    WHERE T2.T1_ID = T1.T1_ID
    );
```

Then, a unique index can be added to prove there are no duplicates remaining, and to prevent future duplicates being inserted:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_T1_SomeData ON dbo.T1(SomeData);
```